# Pardon my mistakes in asking t I have problems solving equations of LIMITS. To be specific the ones I have to rationalize.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, numerical-methods

https://www.ck12.org/book/ck-12-precalculus-concepts/section/14.5/

Example 5.

The last example is what's giving me issues. The denominator at the $4$-th equation to be precise. I don't know how it was manipulated.

Am an undergraduate in the University of Calabar in Nigeria. Am studying for my exams which will commence on 22nd of this month. I believe the answer will help me pass maths exams with good grades and the answer will also help others who have same issue. And I'll definitely reffer my friends to this website. Admin please kindly approve as the responses will help me in no small way. Thanks

Evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3}{x\sqrt{9−x}}-\frac1x\right)$$

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{3}{x\sqrt{9−x}}-\frac1x\right) &= \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{3}{x\sqrt{9−x}}-\frac{\sqrt{9-x}}{x\sqrt{9-x}}\right) \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{9-x}}{x\sqrt{9-x}} \right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{3-\sqrt{9-x}}{x\sqrt{9-x}}\cdot \frac{3+\sqrt{9-x}}{3+\sqrt{9-x}}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{9-(9-x)}{x\sqrt{9-x}}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac1{\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt{9-0}}\\
&= \frac13
\end{align}

Comment: Your title should reflect the actual question you're asking.

Comment: Where do you get lost specifically?

Comment: You're right to be confused because it's wrong. They didn't multiply the denominator by $3+\sqrt{9-x}$

Comment: Please do not delete your question after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to write an answer to your question, and to future readers who might be helped by your question.

Comment: @Xander I promise it won't happen again. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is indeed wrong.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{(3-\sqrt{9-x}}{x\sqrt{9-x}} \cdot \frac{3+\sqrt{9-x}}{3+\sqrt{9-x}} \right) &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{3+\sqrt{9-x}}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{9-(9-x)}{x\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&= \frac16 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{x\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&=\frac16 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac1{\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&=\frac1{18}
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\pm \dfrac{1}{18}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{9}$ as a function maps to only one value, in this case, 3.

Comment: @JaycobColeman there are times where defining $\sqrt{\cdot}$ as a multi-function *can* make sense, but this isn't one of them. Note that if you take values very close to $0$, e.g. $-0.0001$ and $0.0001$ respectively, the original function we're tasked with equals $0.0555551$ and $0.0555560$, which is obviously not negative, and thus, *even if you define $\sqrt{\cdot}$ as a multi-function*, $-\frac{1}{18}$ is an extraneous solution located on a different branch.